# HPUX shell script: split string, put them in an array then loop them

Tags: shell

I have a command output as shown below some examples.

```
E.g.1    {quey_result} -------- .2 .5 .74 (3 rows)
E.g.2    {quey_result} -------- .1 (1 row)
E.g.3    {quey_result} -------- .234 .54 (2 rows)
E.g.4    {quey_result} -------- (0 row)
```

I want to capture each of those decimal numbers (like .2, .5, .74) and use them for some other commands.

Please help me how to trim the beginning and end; then store each decimal values in variable and process, then loop.

Br,
--Shafeer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm assuming that a row looks like:

```
{query_result} -------- .2 .5 .74 (3 rows)
```

And doesn't have "E.g.1" <s>or "(3 rows)"</s>.

```
#!/bin/sh
command | while read -r line
do
    line=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/.*--- \([^(]*\) (.*/\1/'
    set -- $line
    for arg
    do
        do_something_with "$arg"
    done
done
```

<s>This depends on there being no spaces other than the ones you've shown. You can modify the `cut` command or use `awk` to split the line up if needed.</s>

The first two lines inside the `while` loop could be combined into:

```
set -- $(echo "$line" | sed 's/.*--- \([^(]*\) (.*/\1/')
```

Note that either way, if your shell doesn't support `$()` then you'll need to use backticks:

```
`echo "$line" | sed 's/.*--- \([^(]*\) (.*/\1/'`
```

If you have ksh or Bash, there are other ways to do the whole process.

**Edit:** Changed `cut` to `sed`

Comment: Thanks Anders, There is a small correction required in your assumption. The row looks like: {query_result} -------- .2 .5 .74 (3 rows).   "(3 rows)" is part of the row. Could you please tell me how to trim that last part.

Comment: @Shafeer: See my edited answer. (I'm Dennis, by the way, not Anders.)

Comment: Thanks Dennis, as I under your answer will result $line=.2 .5 .74   Let me know if I'm wrong. What I need is, in the first iteration $line=.2, then the code should rea the same ine again, in the second iteration $line=.5, then read line again, in the third iteration $line=.74    I hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: @Shafeer: Yes, `line` will equal ".2 .5 .74", then the `set` command will split it into the positional parameters `$1`, `$2` and `$3`. The `for` loop iterates over the positional parameters so that `arg` is set to each of those values one at a time. `for args` is the same as `for args in "$@"`.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, that worked. One modification set -- "$line" changed to set -- $line  (removed ""). Thanks once again.

Comment: @Shafeer: You are correct about the quotes. I corrected my answer. If you found it helpful, please mark it as accepted.